# PHP code wont post to parse.com on google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, parse-platform

My php file posts fine when I run the file in terminal. However, when I upload the file to Google App Engine, it does not post anything. When I run the file on my localhost as a server I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Parse\curl_init() in
>   /Users/WhiteHeavens/Desktop/TheLoudGuys/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php
>   on line 262

What is going on here and how can I address it?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: modify the **php.ini** :open the **extension=php_curl.dll**; and then restart your Web server  : ）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled the curl extension on the `php.ini` file (located on the root directory of your project).

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

More information: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini

Comment: I did not have a php.ini file. Don't know why I did not know about this? but I made one and added this single line. perfect. thanks.

Comment: hey @angelo could you help me with my CURL.SO issue on google app engine?